# SOAP order inserting: How do you stipulate the payment method?

Tags: orders, soap

I'm attempting to add orders through the soap api.
I am wondering about how to fill in the payment method array

The docs gives this as a sample

```
$paymentMethod =  array(
        'po_number' => null,
        'method' => 'checkmo',
        'cc_cid' => null,
        'cc_owner' => null,
        'cc_number' => null,
        'cc_type' => null,
        'cc_exp_year' => null,
        'cc_exp_month' => null
    );
```

How about when the payment is not CC.. How do we put external transaction numbers in here?  For instance when the order was entered via paypal, I'd like to include the PayPal transaction information (client name, or at least transaction number)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

To enter the payment as paypal (standard) use:

```
$paymentMethod = array(
         'method' => 'paypal_standard',
         'last_trans_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
     );
```

Where xxxxxxxxxxxx is your transaction id. You also need to invoice the order after you created it with the API `salesOrderInvoiceCreate`.

Comment: Given the standard approach, where does this fit into the api calls?

Comment: Ah.. now I see.. though the WSDL indicates the fields in my question are all I can add, I can in fact add more.  Thanks Vlad...

Answer (score 2):

there is a table in magento database which name is "sales_flat_quote_payment", I think those fields below could help:
payment_id
Payment Id
quote_id
Quote Id
created_at
Created At
updated_at
Updated At
method
Method
cc_type
Cc Type
cc_number_enc
Cc Number Enc
cc_last4
Cc Last4
cc_cid_enc
Cc Cid Enc
cc_owner
Cc Owner
cc_exp_month
Cc Exp Month
cc_exp_year
Cc Exp Year
cc_ss_owner
Cc Ss Owner
cc_ss_start_month
Cc Ss Start Month
cc_ss_start_year
Cc Ss Start Year
cybersource_token
paypal_correlation_id
Paypal Correlation Id
paypal_payer_id
Paypal Payer Id
paypal_payer_status
Paypal Payer Status
po_number
Po Number
additional_data
Additional Data
cc_ss_issue
Cc Ss Issue
ideal_issuer_id
ideal_issuer_list
additional_information

Comment: In the context of the API. How would I engage these fields?  I don't see where they fit in.

Comment: I see what you mean, now... With your answer and Vlad's answer I think I see.  I can put any of the fields in the table, into the paymentMethod array.